# How to bind IPv4 to embedded tomcat in maven project?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, ip

When I execute

`request.getRemoteAddr()`

I will receive localhost in IPv6 which is 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1. But what I need is 127.0.0.1 or generally only IPv4. How can I achieve that which embedded tomcat in my maven project?

If I execute `request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")`, would I get IPv4 instead? Because while logging it locally, I received a NULL for that..

Answer (score 0):

In an "normal" Tomcat you need to pass `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to use just IPv4.  You should be able to set an environment variable or, if needed, have some code in the start of you environment something like:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
```

Comment: hi! thank you for the reply, appreciate! do you think that there is another way to do it, by somehow storing the property not in the source code? :)

Comment: @EnyangWang I'm not sure what your code looks like.  "Embedded" could mean alot of things.  I would try to pass the command line version - `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` - to see if that works.  If not you may have to modify some code.  Again though, some more details about what your environment looks like would be useful.  You could modify you existing question with that information.

Comment: where should I put -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true? I am working with Mac terminal and as I have read a lot about start script catalina.sh, I couldnt find any.. Tomcat 8 is embedded in the list of maven dependency in my java project. I will update my question as soon as possible!

Comment: @EnyangWang - if you've got that much then set the environment variable `CATALINA_OPTS`.  Something like `export CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"` on the command line. Realize that this will only be for the terminal you're in where you type it.  If you want that to be for all your environments, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-on-os-x) for details on how to make it "permanent".

Answer (score 0):

You're setting yourself up for failure here. The only way to get `127.0.0.1` as the remote host is if you *only* serve IPV4, and *never* IPV6. While the number of available IPV4 *localhost* addresses doesn't run out soon, the number of public IPV4 addresses does, and it's advisable to be able to talk IPV6 as well. *Any* connection through IPV6 *will* reveal its IPV6 address, naturally.

When you limit yourself to serve only IPV4 addresses, you might not even be able to receive connections addressed as `http://localhost` or `http://localhost:8080`, because localhost, on many current operating systems, denotes `::1`, the IPV6 address. And if you don't listen there, the browser won't be able to connect, unless it connects to `http://127.0.0.1(:8080)` explicitly.

Bite the bullet, change your local logic to cater for IPV4 *and* IPV6 and you're done. On the tomcat side, you're not in control of the address that the connecting browser uses. The browser is.

The `X-Forwarded-For` header is inserted by a proxy. If you don't have a proxy (which is common on localhost connections), it just won't be there (as you observe). And if there was a proxy, it would contain a string representation of the original server - that might be the IPV4 address (if connected through IPV4), the IPV6 address or even a fully qualified domain name. This header has nothing to do with what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Setting env variable `CATALINA_OPTS` as export `CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"` did not help.

However setting `_JAVA_OPTIONS` env variable did the magic.

1. `export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"`  # for permanent put this in `~/.bashrc` and `source ~/.bashrc`
2. `mvn clean install`
3. `java -jar file.jar`
4. `netstat -tunlp` # see tomcat listening to ipv4